# Can a website prevent an element from being added to the already loaded page?

Tags: javascript

If the code below is run in DevTools or in the browser's address bar, the `h1` element will be inserted at the end of a website's page.

```
const elm = document.createElement('h1')
const txt = document.createTextNode('New text')
elm.appendChild(txt)
document.body.appendChild(elm)
```

Can any site prevent this from happening using, for example, `MutationObserver`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to prevent this?

Comment: Indeed, what is the goal here? Why do you want to prevent this in the first place?

Answer (score -2):

A simple way would be to overwrite the `appendChild` on `document.body` so that calling it does nothing.

```js
// page code:
document.body.appendChild = () => {};

// user code:
const elm = document.createElement('h1')
const txt = document.createTextNode('New text')
elm.appendChild(txt)
document.body.appendChild(elm)
```

A MutationObserver would work too - observe the `document.body` for `childNode` changes, and call `.remove()` on all of the added nodes (available inside the callback's parameter).

Comment: These would also prevent the web page's own code from modifying the page, not just the user.

Comment: If that's an additional requirement, either save it in a variable before overwriting, or use `Element.prototype.appendChild.call`

Comment: It's in the question: "If the code below is run in DevTools or in the browser's address bar"

Comment: There's simply far too many ways to get around this (`innerHTML`, `replaceWith()`, etc). OP's question can simply be answered with _"no"_ or at least _"not without significant work"_

Comment: You could also, if you really wanted to, inject jQuery in to the head `d=document;s=d.createElement('script');s.src='jquery-url';d.head.appendChild(s)`
Then `$('body').html('HACKED!')`

Comment: It appeared to me that OP was asking about getting *that* specific piece of code to do nothing, which this approach will do

Comment: @Barmar This information is very useful

Comment: @CertainPerformance the OP is not talking about their website but _all_ websites which makes me think they're up to something unethical.